# View is not showing after push and pop in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to switch from a view to another view, the code runs, but there isn't any view being pushed. Is it due to views are not able to be pop and push simultaneously??

**pushview**:

```
func showChatControllerForGroup(_ user: [User], groupName: String) {

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc: GroupChatMessangingViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "GroupChatMessangingViewController") as! GroupChatMessangingViewController

        vc.group?.members = user
        vc.group?.name = groupName
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

**Pop**

```
 let transition = CATransition()
    transition.duration = 0.5
    transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
    transition.type = kCATransitionReveal
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromBottom
    navigationController?.view.layer.add(transition, forKey: nil)
    _ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        let user = self.chosenUser
        self.nextVC.showChatControllerForGroup(user, groupName: self.groupNameTextField.text!)
```

Comment: If you instantly pop a view after it is pushed then it will disappear. have you tried just not popping it?

Comment: I tried to comment the pop away and only push, it animates a while, but the view stays there..didnt move to the next expected view

Comment: i also tried adding a delay for push, so I can give enough time for the code to pop before pushing, but it stays there...didnt move to next view

Answer (score 0):

just call delegate method before pop viewcontroller

```
let transition = CATransition()
        transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
        transition.type = kCATransitionReveal
        transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromBottom
        navigationController?.view.layer.add(transition, forKey: nil)
    let user = self.chosenUser
            self.nextVC.showChatControllerForGroup(user, groupName: self.groupNameTextField.text!)
        _ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

Comment: still the same result

Comment: @William Loke showChatControllerForGroup this method call or not?.debug code and than tell me

Comment: @William Loke why you want to pop than push view controller i think you need to try direct pushview without pop

Comment: @William Loke remove time duration working perfect.otherwise just pop with simple

Answer (score 0):

Try this syntax for PushViewController:

```
    let nextVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NextViewController") as!   NextViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextVC, animated: true)
```

For pop:

```
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```